# Assigning values to html elements and reading it

Tags: javascript, html, css, algorithm, dom-events

I'm trying to make tic-tac-toe game, basing just on html, CSS and pure js. I have already base of game (there is one bug), but I have problem to detect once someone wins. I've decided to use [MagicSquare](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MagicSquare.html) algorithm, but I don't have idea how to attach value to each td element. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/1c0dqk01/) you can find, what I have at this moment. I'm trying to make something like `player += Number(target.value);` and once one of the players collect 15, then I stop game and display message. Of course, this doesn't work now, so can you advise me some good idea how to assign values with td elements and later read it via js, once player generate click event?

**index.html**

```
<table class="gameArea" onclick="myFunction(event)">
     <tbody>
         <tr>
             <td value=4></td>
             <td value="9"></td>
             <td value="2"></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td value="3"></td>
             <td value="5"></td>
             <td value="7"></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td value="8"></td>
             <td value="1"></td>
             <td value="6"></td>
         </tr>
     </tbody>
</table>
```

**script.js**

```
  var player1 = 0,
      player2 = 0,
      round = 0;

function myFunction(event) {
    var target = event.target;
    //target.className += "x";

    if(hasClass(target, "x") || hasClass(target, "y") ){
      alert("Taken");
      return;
    }

    if(round === 1){
      target.className += "x";
      player1 += Number(target.value);
      round = 0;
      console.log(target.value);
    } else {
      target.className += "y";
      round = 1;
      player2 += Number(target.value);
      console.log("Player 2: " + player2);
    }

    console.log(round);
  }

  function hasClass( elem, klass ) {
   return (" " + elem.className + " " ).indexOf( " "+klass+" " ) > -1;
}
```

Comment: You already must differentiate the tds based on some attribute...you simply have to use it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your HTML to use data attributes, like so:

```
<td data-value="3"></td>
```

You can then read the value, like so:

```
player1 += parseInt(target.dataset.value, 10);
```

More info on MDN [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes).

Comment: Thats exactly what i need! THANKS!

Comment: @DanZawadzki: This is a useful approach, just note that 1. The value is a string, which is why Keir is using `parseInt`, and 2. Some older browsers don't support `dataset`, but you can readily use `target.getAttribute("data-value")` instead on those.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder okay, i will use `getAttribute` method, but will keep `dataset` in my mind anyway

Comment: @DanZawadzki: Yeah, [it's supported in all modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=dataset), it's just obsolete ones that are an issue.

Answer (score 1):

In your *specific* case, you already have the information attached to the element: You have a class, `x` or `y`, which tells you who's marked that square. You can simply use that.

In the general case, there are three common approaches:

1. A separate data cache, keyed by an element's `id` or other unique identifier associated with the element. The idea here is that you give elements unique IDs, and use those IDs as keys into an object that stores the data for the element.

   This is nicely separated from the element (the browser owns the DOM, after all, not our code), but has the issue that entries in the object remain even if an element is removed.

   ES2015 addressed that issue by adding [`WeakMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap), which is a map that can use any value (including a DOM object reference) as a key, and only holds the keys *weakly* (doesn't prevent them being removed from memory). If a key is removed, the entry is removed from the map. So in a browser with native `WeakMap` support (it cannot be correctly shimmed/polyfilled), once you have access to an element, you could do this:

   ```
   // Initializing the map:
   const elementData = new WeakMap();
   // Adding an entry to it:
   elementData.set(theElement, {my: "data"});
   // Getting an entry form it:
   const data = elementData.get(theElement);
   if (data) {
       // It was there, use it...
   }
   ```
2. Storing the data directly on the element, as an "expando" property. Once you have a reference to an element (from `getElementById`, `querySelector`, or any other way), you can create a property on it just by assigning:

   ```
   theElement.__myExpandoProperty = {my: "data"};
   ```

   This is nicely tied to the element, doesn't require a separate data cache and the issues that come with it, gets cleaned up when the element is cleaned up, etc.

   But has the problem that now we're storing our own properties on DOM elements. This raises the possibility of colliding with properties the DOM itself uses, or other scripts use, so it's important to use a name that is extremely unlikely to conflict with something else.

   Separately, in now-obsolete versions of IE, expandos with objects on them (such as the above) had the potential for preventing garbage collection.
3. For string data, using `data-*` attributes on the elements [as Keir points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40718064/157247). I didn't include this in my original list because I was thinking of complex data, but for simple things this is absolutely an option.

jQuery (v2 and earlier) does a combination of #1 and #2: It adds a string expando property to the element to give it an ID (a simple string to avoid issues on now-obsolete versions of IE), and uses a separate data cache.

Comment: Wow! I didnt expect so complex response :). I have decicded to use `getAttribute` method, as it's just 9 numbers to read, but thanks a lot! I have readed and will keep in mind for bigger projects.

Answer (score 1):

First, the way you are getting the value attached with td is wrong.

It should be

```
target.getAttribute('value')
```

not

```
target.value
```

Another issue I think is player sequence,

You are checking

```
if(round === 1){
```

but default value of round = 0, so its the Player 2 who is playing first. You should set default value of round to 1 or compare it to 0 at first.

Just update the code https://jsfiddle.net/1c0dqk01/

Comment: Thanks! I will read about this function, as i had aleady few problems, which can be solved this way really easily! And thanks for point about problem with rounds, you are really right.